# Azure Digital Twins and Azure IoT Edge

Tags: azure-digital-twins

I need to connect Modbus PLC to Azure Digital Twin to send message from several leaf devices.

How do we create Azure Iot edge devices in Azure Digital Twins ?
Then How do we manage IoT edge modules incl deployments, routing, lifecycle,...all the fancy features provided by the embedded IoT Hub ?

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Digital Twins doesn't offer support yet for IoT Edge devices in public preview. We will be looking into this for GA. There is a workaround on this to open the IoT Hub connection string, but we’ve stopped supporting that as we need to focus on the future solution.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the core functionalities presently available for IoT Edge devices are either being incorporated into a future iteration of the service (given the interest and demand following Public Preview). Other, existing, functionalities are being altered to expand interoperability with other customizeable Azure features.

To add a Digital Twins device (a representation within the ADT service only), you may submit an authenticated POST to the Devices API endpoint of your Management API. A future article describing this core functionality is being prepared. For now, please checkout: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/digital-twins/how-to-use-swagger and https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/digital-twins/how-to-navigate-apis for more!

Some of these limits are specified here: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/digital-twins/concepts-service-limits.

Thanks!